# How to fix <Response [400]> error when making a request to the Bitget Futures Rest API in Python?

Tags: python, json, rest, python-requests, http-headers

I am new to using Rest APIs in Python and I'm having trouble sending a request to Bitget Futures. The error I am getting when I attempt to make a request is <Response [400]>. I think the issue may be with the headers that I am passing in.

```
import hashlib
import hmac
import base64
import requests
import time


api_passphrase = [my API passphrase]
api_key = [my API key]
api_sec = [my API secret key]
api_url = "https://api.bitget.com"

symbol = "BTCUSDT_UMCBL"


def bitget_request(request_path, body, query, method):
    std_time = time.time() * 1000
    new_time = int(std_time)
    converted_body = str(body).replace("\'", "\"").replace(" ", "")
    message = str(new_time) + method + request_path + "?" + query + converted_body
    encoded = message.encode()
    signature = hmac.new(base64.b64decode(api_sec), encoded, hashlib.sha256)
    signature = base64.b64encode(signature.digest())
    headers = {"ACCESS-KEY": api_key, "ACCESS-SIGN": signature.decode(), "ACCESS-TIMESTAMP": str(new_time), "ACCESS-PASSPHRASE": api_passphrase, "Content-Type": "application/json", "Locale": "English (en-US)"}
    if method == "GET":
        request_resp = requests.get((api_url + request_path), headers=headers)
    return request_resp


order_resp = bitget_request("/api/mix/v1/account/account", "", "symbol=" + symbol + "&limit=20", "GET")
print(order_resp)
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: @Tarique I edited the post with my code.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of issues with your code:

1. Locale should be set like this: `"Locale": "en-US"`
2. you are not passing query params to `request.get()` call.
3. you are not passing `marginCoin` required param in query. see doc: https://bitgetlimited.github.io/apidoc/en/mix/#get-single-account
4. Signature is not being calculated correctly.

Also try to use as many functions as you can.

here is the code that worked for me:

```
import hashlib
import hmac
import base64
import requests
import time
import json

api_passphrase = "your secret"
api_key = "api key"
api_sec = "api secret"
api_url = "https://api.bitget.com"

symbol = "BTCUSDT_UMCBL"


def parse_params_to_str(params):
    url = '?'
    for key, value in params.items():
        url = url + str(key) + '=' + str(value) + '&'

    return url[0:-1]

def get_signature(message):
    mac = hmac.new(bytes(api_sec, encoding='utf8'), bytes(message, encoding='utf-8'), digestmod='sha256')
    d = mac.digest()
    return base64.b64encode(d)

def bitget_request(request_path, body, query, method):
    std_time = time.time() * 1000
    new_time = int(std_time)
    if str(body) == '{}' or str(body) == 'None':
        converted_body = ''
    else:
        converted_body = json.dumps(body)

    message = str(new_time) + method + request_path + parse_params_to_str(query) + converted_body

    headers = {"ACCESS-KEY": api_key,
               "ACCESS-SIGN": get_signature(message),
               "ACCESS-TIMESTAMP": str(new_time),
               "ACCESS-PASSPHRASE": api_passphrase,
               "Content-Type": "application/json",
               "Locale": "en-US"
               }
    if method == "GET":
        request_resp = requests.get((api_url + request_path), headers=headers, params=query)
    return request_resp

query = {
    "symbol": symbol,
    "marginCoin": "USDT"
}

order_resp = bitget_request("/api/mix/v1/account/account", None, query, "GET")
print(order_resp.json())
```