# Bitget Restful API promblem - how to solve the signature error?

Tags: python, rest

I refer [How to fix <Response [400]> error when making a request to the Bitget Futures Rest API in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72858960/how-to-fix-response-400-error-when-making-a-request-to-the-bitget-futures-re) and succesfully run the get function.
But, even if I follow the Bitget api document to fix the Signature in "POST", I recieve the msg "error sign signature".

**Here is the official document example:**

*(https://bitgetlimited.github.io/apidoc/en/mix/#api-verification)*

*If the queryString is empty, signature content*

*timestamp + method.toUpperCase() + requestPath + body*

*If the queryString not empty, signature content*

*timestamp + method.toUpperCase() + requestPath + "?" + queryString + body*

**Here is my code:**

```
def parse_params_to_str(params):
    url = '?'
    for key, value in params.items():
        url = url + str(key) + '=' + str(value) + '&'

    return url[0:-1]


def get_signature(message):
    mac = hmac.new(bytes(api_sec, encoding='utf8'), bytes(
        message, encoding='utf-8'), digestmod='sha256')
    d = mac.digest()
    return base64.b64encode(d)


def get(request_path, body, query, method):
    std_time = time.time() * 1000
    new_time = int(std_time)
    if str(body) == '{}' or str(body) == 'None':
        converted_body = ''
    else:
        converted_body = json.dumps(body)

    message = str(new_time) + method + request_path + \
        parse_params_to_str(query) + converted_body
    print(message)

    headers = {"ACCESS-KEY": api_key,
               "ACCESS-SIGN": get_signature(message),
               "ACCESS-TIMESTAMP": str(new_time),
               "ACCESS-PASSPHRASE": api_passphrase,
               "Content-Type": "application/json",
               "Locale": "en-US"
               }
    if method == "GET":
        request_resp = requests.get(
            (api_url + request_path), headers=headers, params=query)
    return request_resp


def post(request_path, body,  method):
    std_time = time.time() * 1000
    new_time = int(std_time)

    if str(body) == '{}' or str(body) == 'None':
        converted_body = ''
    else:
        converted_body = json.dumps(body)

    
    message = str(new_time) +method + request_path + converted_body
    print(message)

    
    headers = {"ACCESS-KEY": api_key,
               "ACCESS-SIGN": get_signature(message),
               "ACCESS-TIMESTAMP": str(new_time),
               "ACCESS-PASSPHRASE": api_passphrase,
               "Content-Type": "application/json",
               "Locale": "en-US"
               }
    if method == "POST":
        request_resp = requests.post(
            (api_url + request_path), headers=headers, params=body)
    return request_resp


query = {
    "symbol": symbol,
    "marginCoin": "USDT"
}

order_resp = get("/api/mix/v1/account/account", None, query, "GET")

print(order_resp.json())

para= {"symbol": "BTCUSDT_UMCBL",
        "marginCoin": "USDT",
        "openPrice": "23189.5", 
        "leverage": "20", 
        "openAmount": "5000"}
test = post("/api/mix/v1/account/open-count", para, "POST")
print(test.json())
```

Comment: I am getting the same error on every signed request, POST or GET. If the request is public, I get the data without considering the signature (as expected). Did you solve it?

Answer (score 2):

```
import hashlib
import hmac
import base64
import requests
import json
import time

api_key = "api_key"
secret_key = "secret_key"
passphrase = "passphrase"
base_url = "https://api.bitget.com"
endpoint = "/api/margin/v1/cross/account/borrow"

# Define the payload
payload = {"coin":"TRX","borrowAmount":"10"}

# Convert the payload to JSON format
payload_str = json.dumps(payload)

# Generate the signature
timestamp = str(int(time.time() * 1000))
message = timestamp + "POST" + endpoint + payload_str
signature = base64.b64encode(hmac.new(secret_key.encode('utf-8'), message.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).digest())

# Set the request headers
headers = {
    "ACCESS-KEY": api_key,
    "ACCESS-SIGN": signature,
    "ACCESS-TIMESTAMP": timestamp,
    "ACCESS-PASSPHRASE": passphrase,
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}

# Send the request
response = requests.post(base_url + endpoint, headers=headers, data=payload_str)

# Print the response
print(response.json())
```